# the deletion method isn't working on my sqlite table?

Tags: android, sqlite

first of all i have this code on the main which i call JSON data from a link and insert it into a table then i view the data into a custom list view .. here is the code for the main activity :

```
public class PenddinOrdersTest extends Activity {
    ArrayList<Info> info=new ArrayList<Info>(); 
    static boolean isDataLoaded = false;
    ListView list;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    private String defValue = "N/A";



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pendding_orders);
    setTitle("الطلبات الجديدة");

    if ( databaseHelper == null )
    {
        databaseHelper = new InfoServicesNew(this);
    }

    System.out.println  ( "isDataLoaded:" + isDataLoaded );

    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);

    if ( isDataLoaded )
    {
        rs = databaseHelper.selectAll(name,img);
        SetAdapterList(rs);
    }
    else
    {
        new asy().execute("http://192.168.1.113/JsonRoot/transitions/Pendding_orders.json");

    }
} 

private void SetAdapterList(ArrayList<Info> result) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    CustomAdapter adapter=new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), result);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    System.out.println ( "Size : " + list.getCount() );
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i=new Intent(PenddinOrdersTest.this,Details.class);
            int myId=arg2;

            object = list.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            Info detail = (Info) object;

            String client = detail.getClient();
            String orderAmount = detail.getOrderAmount();
            String date=detail.getdate();
            String orderNumber=detail.getorderNumber();
            String upperLimit=detail.getupperLimit();
            String debt=detail.getdept();

            i.putExtra("myid", ""+myId);
            i.putExtra("client", ""+ client);
            i.putExtra("orderAmount", ""+orderAmount);
            i.putExtra("date", date);
            i.putExtra("orderNumber", orderNumber);
            i.putExtra("upperLimit", upperLimit);
            i.putExtra("debt", debt);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
    //    
}

public class asy extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<Info>>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd.setTitle("fetching");
        pd.setMessage("waiting...");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Info> doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //activity is defined as a global variable in your AsyncTask

        try {

            HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet hg = new HttpGet(params[0]);
            HttpResponse hr = hc.execute(hg);
            HttpEntity he = hr.getEntity();
            data = EntityUtils.toString(he);
            Log.i("data", data);

        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ArrayList<Info> sereenlist = new ArrayList<Info>();
        sereenlist = getJSONData(data);

        return sereenlist;
    }


    private ArrayList<Info> getJSONData(String data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String id = null;
        String item=null;
        String amount=null;
        String unit=null;
        String price=null;
        String total_price=null;

        ArrayList<Info> rs = null;

        if ( isDataLoaded == false  )
        {
            try 
            {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray finalObj = obj.optJSONArray("orders");
                for (int i = 0; i < finalObj.length(); i++) 
                {

                    final String orderNumber = finalObj.optJSONObject(i).optString(
                            "order-number");
                    final String orderAmount = finalObj.optJSONObject(i).optString(
                            "order-amount");
                    final String date = finalObj.optJSONObject(i).optString(
                            "date");
                    final String client = finalObj.optJSONObject(i).optString(
                            "client");
                    final String upperLimit = finalObj.optJSONObject(i).optString(
                            "upper-limit");
                    final String debt = finalObj.optJSONObject(i).optString(
                            "debt");
                    JSONArray details = finalObj.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("details");

                    for(int j=0; j<details.length(); j++)
                    {
                        id = details.getJSONObject(j).optString("id");
                        item = details.getJSONObject(j).optString("item");
                        amount = details.getJSONObject(j).optString("amount");
                        unit = details.getJSONObject(j).optString("unit");
                        price = details.getJSONObject(j).optString("price");
                        total_price = details.getJSONObject(j).optString("total-price");
                    }

                    long id1=databaseHelper.insert(new Info(client,orderAmount,date,orderNumber,upperLimit,debt,img),name);
                    databaseHelper.insert_details(new Details_info(id,item,amount,unit,price,total_price,orderNumber),name2);
                }
                rs = databaseHelper.selectAll(name,img);
                Log.i("size", finalObj.length()+"");
            }//try end

            catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return rs;
    }

    @Override//
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Info> result) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //SetAdapterList(result);
        isDataLoaded = true;
        rs = databaseHelper.selectAll(name,img);
        SetAdapterList(rs);         
        pd.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override 
public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    if ( databaseHelper != null )
    {
        databaseHelper.close();
    }
    System.out.println ( "db closed" );
}
```

}

and each time i click on an item it goes to Details activity which display data from a get intent .. and if i click the (approve) button it should delete a row from a custom adapter .. but the function isn't working .. here is a the Details code :

```
  public class Details extends Activity {


          InfoServicesNew databaseHelper;

         String name2=InfoServicesNew.DB_TABLE_NAME5;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {




            approve.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent=new Intent(Details.this,PenddinOrdersTest.class);
                    databaseHelper.delete(id,name2);


                    if(id < 0)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "unsuccessfull delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        startActivity(intent);


                }
            });


            details.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try{

                    ArrayList<Details_info> rs = null;
                    //rs=databaseHelper.selectAllDetails(name2);
                    //Log.i("rs",rs+"");

                    Intent intent=new Intent(Details.this,Order_info.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally{
                        //databaseHelper.close();
                    }
                    //
                }

            });




    }
    }
```

and lastly here is the method body in the sqlite helper .. any help please??

```
public long delete(int id, String name2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return database.delete(name2, KEY_ID + " = " + id, null) ;
    }
```

Comment: do you really have to post all of this code including all of the imports.

Comment: Quickly browsing there seems to be many things wrong with the code. Expecting the community to debug it all for you is a lot to ask. Please try to debug the code yourself and if you have specific problems, ask specific questions.

Comment: i post everything to make it clear :/

Comment: what is the return value of your delete method? Either it is 0 or any int Number.